# What's the Microsoft font that looks same/closer to 'Estrangelo Edessa'?

Tags: winforms, fonts, typeface

I am facing display issues with winforms in window 10 OS. The fonts used for forms is 'Estrangelo Edessa’. In windows 10, this font doesn't come installed by default and hence text/content looks ugly (cutoff/improperly sized). So i am thinking to change the font that looks closer to 'Estrangelo Edessa' and will be native to windows 7, 8 and 10. Please suggest one such font.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying Verdana or Lucida Sans Unicode as they have similar proportions to Estrangelo Edessa. Alternatively, Calibri is narrower but otherwise similar and nicer to read.

You may also want to look into having your forms size the controls so text is never cut off, just in case. For example, all WinForms controls have a `PreferredSize` property.

Comment: Thank you. I went for Verdana.

Comment: I did it. But since my reputation is <15, it's been recorded but not shown public. :(